# Inequalities with random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have some doubts regarding random variables in inequations. Suppose I have two equations as:

1st eq: $X+c$

2nd eq: $X + d$

where $X$ is a random variable and $c, d,$ any arbitrary number in $\mathbb{R}$.

If I want to compare both equations, for instance to see if 1st < 2nd, is this ok?

$X + c < X +d \Rightarrow c < d$, i.e., 1st equation will be less than 2nd if $c < d$

I assumed that $X$ can be simplified since it is the same random variable, with the same probability distribution, in both sides of the inequation.

Is that correct, or shall I first compute the probability distribution of $X+c$ (in the same way, $X+d$) and then use stochastic ordering definition to check if 1st < 2nd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two $X$ that are collected differently refers to the same object, $\color{blue}{X} + c$ and $\color{red}{X}+d$, then yup, you just have to compare $c$ and $d$.

However, if $\color{blue}{X_1} + c$ and $\color{red}{X_2}+d$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ follows the same distribution but they do not refer to the same hting, then no. We will have to study the distribution of $X_1-X_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the tips